# Integrating Google Images into App

Tags: xml, ios, image, synchronization, fetch

I just have a general question: has anyone successfully implemented a way to show a google image of a term in an iOS app (or any app, for that matter). Say the user types in 'rocket launch', the app fetches a random image from Google. I need a way to do this, but I'm curious on the legality of it. Does Google allow us to do this? Or does anyone? Any help / suggestions are much appreciated!

Zach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a google image search API: http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/.  Which has been recently deprecated, but is still functional.  They just limit the number of requests you can make.

ian.

Comment: can i use that (it's javascript) in an iOS app?

Comment: Yes, you can do it, there are several examples of apps that have, i.e. http://www.iosnoops.com/appinfo/picsearch-google-image-search-for-iphone/326245427

Comment: Is it a bad idea to use a deprecated technology? will they we slowly killing it? I don't want to implement a technology that is going to be shutoff at some point in the near future

Answer (score 0):

You can UIWebView to search. Create your query URL and then pass the webView to load URL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From what I understand, Apple has been really cutting back on what they allow with the UIWebView. They don't like it, and it's means for rejection a lot of times. Furthermore, it really wouldn't work seamlessly. What I meant was that the app fetches it on its own - no user intervention

Comment: @Zakman411 It will better to use instead of deprecated API's.